# Best load balancing algorithm to distribute requests across a group of servers?

Tags: algorithm, load-balancing

Which is the better load balancing algorithm to distribute incoming requests across a group of servers? I've read that they are some algorithms like Round Robin.. but I'd like to know your opinions about which is the better or at least most used algorithm for this.

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: it depends. the best load balancing is achieved when considering multiple factors which are specific to the service. For example, say you have a service which provides an API to encode a string, where the encoding depends purely on the content of the string. You have N replicas of the service running.

One simple approach would be to simply have a client pick service index i = hash(string)/N. Assuming that the input string are uniformily distributed on the hashing space, this will work well and is very easy to implement.

Say now for some reason that for some reason the strings are not well distributed on the hashing space (maybe a lot of string may be repeated, for example). In this case you could use a simple approach of doing round-robin, or randomly selecting an index. You could also have a measure of back pressure from the servers: for example, if an RPC call is synchronous, you could measure at the client side how long it takes and, in the case of string encoding, divide that by the length of the string; if a client notices this number going up, it probably means the service is not being able to keep up and the client could reduce the traffic it sends to such client. This is obviously a little more complex.

TLDR: There are many options for load balancing, which one is "the best"depends on the specific nature of the problem being scaled.

Answer (score 1):

With HTTP servers, Round Robin, Weight Round Robin and Random are the probably the most used and safest patterns to use since they do not create hotspots that are caused by trying to determine which host to send to.

I understand that a multi-tier approach can be used to even out the distribution of requests. This is where you have 2 clusters that are Round Robined and each cluster has several servers that have random distribution.

Least connections and Fastest response rely on predicting the performance of each server based on past performance. Whilst they can be useful for certain types of load - say lots of long running connections, they can be problematic with high traffic web-servers as they can cause a flood of requests to a newly deployed server or one that just crashed.

The ideal load balancing algorithm is one that is not really supported by HTTP - 'Competing consumers'. This is the way many queue systems work (eg RabbitMq). The clients pull the messages rather than have them pushed to them. The one that is fastest to take the work 
 - and therefore most available to perform it -  will be given it.

HTTP web-servers are push based rather than pull so this pattern doesn't really fit.

However, it's possible to build this kind of solution yourself using an intermediary proxy that implements a request-response pattern but it comes with it's own set of challenges.

I wrote a bit about it here: [https://www.quora.com/Why-use-message-queues-for-a-request-response-pattern-which-is-synchronous-when-queues-are-asynchronous/answer/Tom-Burnell-5?**nsrc**=4&**snid3**=6113161011](https://www.quora.com/Why-use-message-queues-for-a-request-response-pattern-which-is-synchronous-when-queues-are-asynchronous/answer/Tom-Burnell-5?__nsrc__=4&__snid3__=6113161011)

Answer (score 0):

1- Round Robin

2- Weighted Round Robin

3- Least Connections

4- Weighted Least Connections

5- Random

please see this url:

https://www.jscape.com/blog/load-balancing-algorithms